# How would I run integration tests from vivet/googleApi?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to work out how I would integrate this shared library from GitHub into my code, since it is a shared class library, for starters I just want to run the integration tests, but I cannot work out how go get the test runner to run them.

I created a console application in my main project and a reference to the GoogleMapsApiTest in the console but I am not sure how to call the tests from there to run them.

[GoogleAPIClassLibrary](https://github.com/vivet/GoogleApi)

I had to download the gui test runner and build it from GitHub. [Link to project](https://github.com/CharliePoole/nunit-gui)
 now I can at least run the tests, I am still not sure how to use the library but that should  help at least see how it is supposed to work.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to run the unit tests by downloading the NUnit source code at the link in my post and then browsing to the output dll of the class project, to load the tests apparently the gui-test runner is no longer available for download, so hopefully that will help someone else out if they run into a need for running tests in NUnit.